# youtube video play button not working for youtube embedded video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

Just found a new issue, the client is saying the play button is not working on the youtube embedded video. It only seems to not work on mobiles, I have tested it on iphone and sony phones and does not work on either but works when viewing the site on computer.

The code is below

```
<div class="item active" style="">
                        <!--<iframe width="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/3a3kT55-fF0?enablejsapi=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" id="video" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
    <iframe width="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/3a3kT55-fF0?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&ps=docs&controls=1" frameborder="0" id="video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4 class=""></h4>
            <p class="">
                               </p>
                        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    // Inject YouTube API script
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

   var player;

   function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
   // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
   player = new YT.Player('video', {
   events: {
  // call this function when player is ready to use
  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
   }
   });
   }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {

       $("#myCarousel").carousel('pause');
    }

  else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){

          $("#myCarousel").carousel('cycle');
   }
   }

   function onPlayerReady(event) {

   // bind events
   $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e){
   //alert($(e.relatedTarget).index();
   if($(e.relatedTarget).index()!=0 && YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){
   //alert('A new slide is about to be shown!');
   player.pauseVideo();
   }
   });

   }

   </script>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code on jsbin. It seems to be fine in both desktop and mobile.
https://jsbin.com/nurokiyaju

Comment: weird, am wondering if it's something with the cms system that is integrated

Comment: do you get any error or any messages on those devices

Comment: Is there any way to find out on safari on iphone?

Comment: Is the link which I shared on comments working on iPhone? If not please share a screenshot

Comment: Yeah the link worked on my iphone and played the video with no issue

Comment: Screenshot of yours where you are getting errors, please?

Comment: Think I sorted the issue now, think the issue was the caption div was overlaying on top of the play button so adjusted some of the code and is working now